# regression.fit(x_train, y_train) is not working on python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, pandas, numpy

I try to deal with my homework. The Job is to take the Achievement data and perform a multi-linear regression on it.

The code is published [here](https://github.com/atyh19/achievement.git).

I am quite new to programming in Python and in data science. I obtained a R2 value to be  -0.03558318907299585 which is too wrong to be true. I tried to incoporate and make my array into numpy but it still doesn't seem to work. Does anyone know how I could perform this linear regression?

Comment: Looking at the code I don't think anything is inherently wrong, just that your current model seems to not perform very well. Based on the scatter plot I think that the large outlier with a true value of close to 160 has a big impact on your model's score.

Comment: Perhaps you could try it with [`PolynomialFeatures`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures.html#sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures).

Comment: @Oxbowerce, thank you for your feedback! Appreciate it :)

Comment: @rickhg12hs, ok! I shall try that thank you :))

Comment: Could it be a shape issue? X is shape (N, 3) but Y is a list of length N. Try getting rid of the np.squeeze so that it is shape (N, 1).